# Ionic and Firebase - InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, ionic3

I am having issue getting a basic CRUD to-do list app using Ionic 3 and Firebase to work.

The error message I am stuck on is:

*Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'*

The error message started when I added the `<ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingListRef$ | async">` section to shopping-list.html:

**shopping-list.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Shopping List</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="navigateToAddShoppingPage()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingListRef$ | async">
      <h2>Item Name: {{item.itemName}}</h2>
      <h3>Amount: {{item.itemNumber}}</h3>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I have tried commenting out the code between `<ion-item>` and `</ion-item>` in the file above, and that removes the error message.  However, can't figure out how to fix it.

Here are some relevant files involved.

**shopping-list.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AddShoppingPage } from '../add-shopping/add-shopping';
import { ShoppingItem } from '../../models/shopping-item/shopping-item.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: 'shopping-list.html',
})
export class ShoppingListPage {

  shoppingListRef$: FirebaseListObservable<ShoppingItem[]>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.shoppingListRef$ = this.database.list('shopping-list');
  }

  navigateToAddShoppingPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AddShoppingPage)
  }
}
```

**shopping-item.interface.ts**

```
export interface ShoppingItem {
    itemName: string;
    itemNumber: number;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas / help you may have!

Comment: which version of angularfire you are using?

Comment: I am using angularfire2 - you can see in shopping-list.ts in `import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';` @HamedBaatour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are using the new angularfire2 version which is version 5 in this case you should be doing the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: 'shopping-list.html',
})
export class ShoppingListPage {
 shoppingListRef$: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.shoppingListRef$ = this.database.list('shopping-list').valueChanges();;
  }
}
```

as starting from version 5 `database.list` no longer returns an observable so you can't subscribe to it in the template using the `async` pipe. this is why you should chain the `valueChanges()` method which returns an Observable in this case.

Comment: This worked, but rather than make all of the changes indicated above, I simply made one change to chain the `valueChanges();`method.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adam great! glad that this helped you. I asked you in the beginning about your version of `angularfire2` but I had to guess to help you out  ;)

Comment: Yes, I saw that - I did not realize that angularfire2 had different version but now I know for next time.  Thanks!

Comment: @HamedBaatour `valueChanges()` method working but I'm not getting `$key` which we were getting in observable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515158/ionic3-error-error-uncaught-in-promise-error-invalidpipeargument-objec please check