# Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe '

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

Hello    i    need    help     solving     this    :
 what   does   this   error   mean?
I   can' t   figure  it     out  ,  I    tried    many   things   but    nothing
helped  .  This   is   my   code. and this is the tutorial i used for it:
https://devdactic.com/ionic-firebase-angularfire/

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' Error: 
InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' at invalidPipeArgumentError 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44334:12) at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44479:15) at AsyncPipe._subscribe 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44465:31) at AsyncPipe.transform 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:44443:22) at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]         
(ng:///AppModule/HomePage.ngfactory.js:136:73) at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as 
updateDirectives] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13450:21) at checkAndUpdateView 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12627:14) at callViewAction 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12995:21) at execComponentViewsAction 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12927:13) at checkAndUpdateView 
(http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12633:5)
```

home.ts:

```
import { FirebaseProvider } from './../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  shoppingItems: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  newItem = ''; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseProvider: 
  FirebaseProvider) {
    this.shoppingItems = this.firebaseProvider.getShoppingItems();
  }
  addItem() {
    this.firebaseProvider.addItem(this.newItem);
  }
  removeItem(id) {
    this.firebaseProvider.removeItem(id);
  }
}
```

this is my html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Shopping List
    </ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>
</ion-header> 
<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-9>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem" placeholder="New 
          Shopping item"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button (click)="addItem()">Add!</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">
      <ion-item>
        {{ item.$value }}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button color="danger" icon-only 
        (click)="removeItem(item.$key)"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-
        icon></button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and this is my firebase.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 
'angularfire2/database'; 

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseProvider {
  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getShoppingItems() {
   return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/');
  }

  addItem(name) {
   this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').push(name);
  }

  removeItem(id) {
    this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').remove(id);
  }

}
```

Comment: It means `InvalidPipeArgument`.. You need to provide [mcve] for anyone to help you

Comment: @SurajRao sorry for that i updated my post

Comment: where are you using AsyncPipe here? please add that html as well

Comment: @SurajRao i added it also this is the tutorial i followed https://devdactic.com/ionic-firebase-angularfire/

Comment: ok..hmm. which version of angularfire2? Check your package.json

Comment: @SurajRao i have firebase 3.14.0 also     "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",

Comment: can you show the `.getShoppingItems()` call please. I think you are missing something there

Comment: i only have this in my code `this.shoppingItems = this.firebaseProvider.getShoppingItems();`

Comment: no the function definition in your provider where you access firebase list

Comment: of course sorry for that `getShoppingItems() {
    return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/');
  }`

Comment: can you console log shoppingItems?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/558

Comment: oh okay! console log isn't working

Comment: what is printing?

Comment: okk so I added it it worked and it added the data in the firebade database but it didn't show on my screen so i can remove

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611944/ionic-and-firebase-invalidpipeargument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe you should use `Observable` instead of `FirebaseListObservable`.

Comment: @hrdkisback i solved this problen but now i have a problem with `<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">` everything is working as they should but `<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">` is not printing on screen

Answer (score 0):

remove `| async` from

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">
```

use it like this

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems ">
```