# ionic3 - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I did a news comment function by ionic3 with firebase, after testing comment function working already, but when I want the comment showing in my project error coming out.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument:
>   '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

My project follow this [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8Ijo3LeIhk&index=56&list=PLvm96AauOfl_eNl_2Yh7-y2ZO_0IMROC2).

**html file**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-group *ngFor="let contact of contactsList | async">
    <ion-item>
      {{contact.$value}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
</ion-list>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Contact" placeholder="写评论..."></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="addContact()">发布</button>
            </ion-col>      
        </ion-row>
    </ion-list>
```

**ts file**

```
 import { AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

 export class NewsDetailPage {
  new: any;
  contactsList:AngularFireList<any>;
  Contact = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private qq: QQSDK, private socialSharing: SocialSharing,
    public firebaseService:FirebaseServiceProvider,public alertCtrl: AlertController
    // private photoViewer: PhotoViewer
  ) {
    this.new = navParams.get('new');
    this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList();
  }

  addContact() {
    this.firebaseService.addContact(this.Contact);

    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: '评论成功！',
      //subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['确认']
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

```
  getContactsList() {
    return this.angularfiredb.list('/contactsList/');
  }
```

Comment: Before your `<ion-list>` just try outputting your `contactsList` variable as json like this, `<div>contactsList|json</div>` and see if it is a complex object.

Comment: I update my `ts` file, please check

Comment: which is your version of angularfire?

Comment: @SurajRao angularfire2, download from here..https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: ye3s.. am asking its version.. is it 5.x?

Comment: yes. version 5.x

Comment: ok.. can you add `getContactsList()` function code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164151/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-suraj-rao).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first convert the AngularFireList to an Observable :

```
contactsList: Observable<any[]>;
```

And in your constructor, you need to call `valueChanges()` on it. This is since AngularFire2 Version 5.

```
this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList().valueChanges();
```

This will return the data through the observable without `$key` or `$value`.
In order to print in html,use

```
  {{contact}}
```

instead of

```
  {{contact.$value}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `contactsList` declaration from

`contactsList:AngularFireList<any>;`

to

`contactsList: Observable<any[]>;`

Ensure that you're importing your `Observable` module as,

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

Also your `contactList` variable assignment should be changed as,

```
this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList().valueChanges();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But what should I import in my `ts` file

Comment: error showing: `cannot find Observable` , and when I import it to `angularfire2/database` also showing error.

Comment: Please import `Observable` module like this, `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` and then try again

Comment: Showing error in `this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList();`, should I update my firebase-service providers

Comment: `Can not assign type "AngularFireList <{}>" to type "Observable <any []>".
   Missing attribute "_isScalar" in type "AngularFireList <{}".`

Comment: Can you please try changing your `this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList();` as `this.contactsList = this.firebaseService.getContactsList().valueChanges();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164147/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-david-r).

Comment: @YuyangHe Updated my answer, Kindly accept! Thanks!