# this.angularFireList.remove is not a function

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Hi I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHTBnTg4rno&list=PLtKjv92L0ihAJ90_NbqCINRu4uKy3RJJU&index=13) and now I am unable to remove a record from firebase realtime database.

(updated 11 June 2018) -- previously I was suspecting this error comes when I use FirebaseListObservable, however it turns out the error also happens when using AngularFireList.

### Using AngularFireList

```
Runtime Error
_this.produkkuListRef.remove is not a function
```

This is the page which has a remove function:

**fleks-bisnis-produkku.module.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { ProdukItem } from '../../models/produk-item/produk-item.interface';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fleks-bisnis-produkku',
  templateUrl: 'fleks-bisnis-produkku.html',
})
export class FleksBisnisProdukkuPage {

  produkkuList: AngularFireList<ProdukItem[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase,
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {

    this.produkkuListRef = this.database.list('produk-list').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.produkkuListRef);
  }

  selectProdukItem(produkItem: ProdukItem){

    this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: `${produkItem.itemName}`,
      buttons:[
        {
          text: 'Edit',
          handler: () => {
             // send the user to the EditProdukItemPage and pass the key as a parameter
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          handler: () => {
            //delete the current ProdukItem, passed in via the parameter
            console.log(this.produkkuListRef);
            this.produkkuListRef.remove(produkItem.$key);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log("The user has selected the cancel button");
          }
        }
      ]
    }).present();
  }

  pushToTambahProduk(){
    this.navCtrl.push('FbTambahProdukPage')
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FleksBisnisProdukkuPage');
  }

}
```

### Using FirebaseListObservable

```
Runtime Error
_this.produkkuListRef$.remove is not a function
```

This is the page which has a remove function:

**fleks-bisnis-produkku.module.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { ProdukItem } from '../../models/produk-item/produk-item.interface';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fleks-bisnis-produkku',
  templateUrl: 'fleks-bisnis-produkku.html',
})
export class FleksBisnisProdukkuPage {

  produkkuListRef: FirebaseListObservable<ProdukItem[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase,
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {

    this.produkkuListRef$ = this.database.list('produk-list').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.produkkuListRef$);
  }

  selectProdukItem(produkItem: ProdukItem){

    this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
      title: `${produkItem.itemName}`,
      buttons:[
        {
          text: 'Edit',
          handler: () => {
             // send the user to the EditProdukItemPage and pass the key as a parameter
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          role: 'destructive',
          handler: () => {
            //delete the current ProdukItem, passed in via the parameter
            console.log(this.produkkuListRef$);
            this.produkkuListRef$.remove(produkItem.$key);
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log("The user has selected the cancel button");
          }
        }
      ]
    }).present();
  }

  pushToTambahProduk(){
    this.navCtrl.push('FbTambahProdukPage')
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FleksBisnisProdukkuPage');
  }

}
```

### Other References

this is my interface file that is imported to the page above

**produk-item.interface.ts**

```
export interface ProdukItem{
    $key?: string;
    itemName: string;
    itemHarga: number;
}
```

this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "go-fleksales",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I've been searching on google, and it seems that my code is correct. What could be causing this error?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `this.produkkuListRef$` as follows:

```
this.produkkuListRef$ = this.database.list('produk-list').valueChanges();
```

It returns "an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects.", according to the [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md).

You cannot call `remove()` on this object, you have to do it on the list itself, like:

```
this.produkkuList1Ref$ = this.database.list('produk-list');
....
this.produkkuList1Ref$.remove(produkItem.$key)
```

see this [part](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list) of the doc.

Comment: Hi Renaud, thank you for your response. As your suggestion, I have removed the `.valueChanges()` so it becomes: `this.produkkuListRef$ = this.database.list('produk-list');`. However it returns another error when the page loads (before I even call the remove function) `Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` . This issue is already addressed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611944/ionic-and-firebase-invalidpipeargument-object-object-for-pipe-asyncpipe).

Comment: Hi Renaud, I have updated my post above. It turns out that the error message persists regardless of using `FirebaseListObservable` or `AngularFireList`. Is there any other possible workaround?

Comment: @BrianIvanderT.P. Unfortunately I am not very well-versed with angularfire, but I would try to reproduce the example your find in the doc: "Deleting the entire list" at https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md.

Comment: Hi Renaud, tried "Delete the entire list" by not specifying the key parameter, but the error `Runtime Error
_this.produkkuListRef$.remove is not a function` still persists. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @BrianIvanderT.P. Sorry I was not 100% clear in my last comment. When I suggest you try to reproduce the example, it is not really to change how you call remove, but the beginning of the example, how they declare `AngularFireList` and `this.items`. Again I am not very well-versed with angularfire so consider this as a trial and error approach...